# How to submit job when Spark jobs have very different executor resource requirements

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

Let's say I have a job with the following:

Job 1: long-running CPU bound
Job 2: Needs a large heap in each executor

I'd love to be able to run Job 1 with low memory and Job 2 with more memory.  Is my only option to break it up into separate applications that can be submitted (to my YARN cluster) with separate executor configs?